# How to make Data save ASP.Net

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, http-post

I have been making an ASP.Net application and am struggling to get Data to save. I used this tutorial to for everything but it does not mention how to save data:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio
When I close and re-open the app, it looses all stored data. 
I'm guessing I should post the data to a JSON file and save it there?

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The intent of the above link was only to cover WebAPI related topic that is the reason they are saving data in memory.

The link you followed already used SqlServer provider, you just need to add a database connection to store data permanently.

You can follow below link to understand, how real time application use SQL server to store and retrieve data.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/intro?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Hope it will help!

Comment: Thank you. Will have a look

Comment: The WebApi used json for its requests, so I developed my app around that. The one you linked doesn't use json and I'm struggling to link the two up. I don't see how I the DB will be made into the JSON form

Comment: You don't need to use asp.net MVC Razor page, just focus on Entity framework part. You have already used Entity framework, you need to understand how to pass the database connection string instead in-memory.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/intro?view=aspnetcore-3.1#register-the-schoolcontext

Comment: You're a star! Thank you so much